# Creating multithreading for square root operation

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to create C program that initiates 8 threads, each thread does square roots. 8 threads need to take care of all number starting 1 to 10000 and outputs into .txt file. I have created this code but having a lot of errors. Please any help/hints needed.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 8
#define START_NUMBER 1
#define END_NUMBER 10000


FILE *f;

void *square_operation(void *tid)
{

for (i=(START_NUMBER+tid); i<=END_NUMBER; i++) {
    fprintf(f, "%lu squared = %lu\n", i, i*i);
    i+=7;
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
// START: Do not modify anything here
struct timeval start_time, end_time;
gettimeofday(&start_time, 0);
long unsigned i;
f = fopen("./squared_numbers.txt", "w");
// END: Do not modify anything here

/* The main program creates 8 threads and then exits */
pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
long status, i;
for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
{
    status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, square_operation, (void *)i);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("Oops. pthread_create returned error code %0d\n", status);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

/* Wait for all threads to finish, before exiting process */
for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
{
    if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL))
    { printf("Thread %0d failed to join\n"); }
}
exit(1);


// START: Do not modify anything here
fclose(f);
gettimeofday(&end_time, 0);
float elapsed = (end_time.tv_sec-start_time.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + \
(end_time.tv_usec-start_time.tv_usec) /1000.0f;
printf("took %0.2f milliseconds\n", elapsed);
// END: Do not modify anything here
}
```

so i get these errors:

```
prog2.c:16:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (i=(START_NUMBER+tid); i<=END_NUMBER; i++) {
         ^
prog2.c:16:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (i=(START_NUMBER+tid); i<=END_NUMBER; i++) {
                               ^
prog2.c:16:47: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (i=(START_NUMBER+tid); i<=END_NUMBER; i++) {
                                              ^
prog2.c:17:43: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        fprintf(f, "%lu squared = %lu\n", i, i*i);
                                          ^
prog2.c:18:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        i+=7;
        ^
prog2.c:33:18: error: redefinition of 'i' with a different type: 'long' vs
      'unsigned long'
    long status, i;
                 ^
prog2.c:27:19: note: previous definition is here
    long unsigned i;
                  ^
prog2.c:39:70: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'long' [-Wformat]
            printf("Oops. pthread_create returned error code %0d\n", status);
                                                             ~~~     ^~~~~~
                                                             %0ld
prog2.c:48:28: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
        { printf("Thread %0d failed to join\n"); }
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: this is the error `prog2.c:16:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for (i=(START_NUMBER+tid); i<=END_NUMBER; i++) {`

Comment: I know i declared `long unsigned i;` in main but the chunks of code you see I cant modify

Comment: You should mentioned the errors or problem in your question. So we don't have to guess what is wrong.

Comment: Also this `prog2.c:36:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'threads'
        status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, square_operation, (void *)i);` but i think i declared threads already...

Comment: Alright let me edit it, sorry im new to this..

Comment: You need to declare `i` within the `square_operation` function. That's part of the code that you can change right? And you have declared `i` twice in `main`. Remove the second definition as it is not needed.

Comment: Yes, I can edit that.

Comment: So I declared i within the loop `for (int i=(START_NUMBER+tid); i<=END_NUMBER; i++)` but i still got this error `prog2.c:33:18: error: redefinition of 'i' with a different type: 'long' vs
      'unsigned long'
    long status, i;`

Comment: See the second part of my above comment.

Comment: Yes, but the second definition I cant alter, its within the chunk i cant modify

Comment: Why can't you modify it? It is **after** `// END: Do not modify anything here`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104945/discussion-between-anastasia-netz-and-kaylum).

Comment: My time doesnt display at all...Nevermind, got it!

Comment: you might want to look at this search for this question on stackoverflow.com:  "Squaring numbers w/ multiple threads"  as most of the problems and how to overcome then are the same as yours, except the other question is performing a `square` rather than a `squareroot`

Comment: why is the posted code contain this line: `exit(1);`?  it effectively means that the bottom 1/4th of the code will never be executed.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: please consistently indent the code, use meaningful variable names, only declare one variable per statement and only one statement per line

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared any variable called i in square operations.
Maybe in main, but because of c's scope mechanism, it is not visible in sqare operations.
That should reduce your compiler error log.